# Magento 2 - How to get admin user role?

Tags: magento2, admin, session, user-roles

I want to get all information of user(admin) and I find this answer for M1:
To get an admin user role try (assuming that user is log in)

```
$admin_user_session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$adminuserId = $admin_user_session->getUser()->getUserId();
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($adminuserId)->getRole()->getData();
```

Now I want get this for Magento 2.0. And how to do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use DI in your class -
1. add property of AdminSession class to class
2. add including of the variable using dependensy injection:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session
 */
protected $_adminSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession
) {
    $this->_adminSession = $adminSession;
}
```

and then where you need to use it:

```
public function someMethod()
{
    $roleData = $this->_adminSession->getUser()->getRole()->getData();
    $userData = $this->_adminSession->getUser()->getData();
}
```

Comment: after I tried, have a problem below: Fatal error: Call to a member function getRole() on null in

Comment: I want get admin session at front-end.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $_context ;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
) {
$this->_context = $context;
}

public function customfucntion()
{
  $auth          = $this->_context->getAuth();
  $loginUser     = $auth->getUser();
  $loginUserRole = $loginUser->getRole();
  $loginUserRole->getRoleName();
}
```