# How to detect the Admin status of the current user?

Tags: magento-2.1, user, admin-user

Is there any way I can detect if the currently logged in user is an admin user?

I am trying to prevent non-admin users from processing orders.
Thanks your response is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create differents roles for the users from admin panel in **System -> Permissions -> User Roles**. You can assign the resources of each role there.

In **System -> Permissions -> All Users** you can specify the role of each user.

Comment: Yes, i figured this out, but in code what if i want to check if the currently logged in user of the admin section is not a super admin (permitted to do everything)

Comment: Yo can create a role subadmin with all resources and then, in the code get the role of the logged in user. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103582/magento-2-how-to-get-admin-user-role

Comment: @Koothrapali could, did it work??