# Get admin detail via load by user_id in magento 2

Tags: admin, email

```
username = 'admin';
$user_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('username',$username)->getData();
var_dump($user_data);

//By Username get admin User's Role Details
$username = 'admin';
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('username',$username)->getFirstItem()->getRole()->getData();
var_dump($role_data);

//By ID get admin User's Details
$id = 1;
$user_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($id)->getData();
var_dump($user_data);


//By ID get admin User's Role Details
$id = 1;
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($id)->getRole()->getData();
var_dump($role_data);
```

this code for magento1 . am working on magento 2 . can anyone guide me how get user detail of specific user_id.

Comment: please try : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103582/magento-2-how-to-get-admin-user-role OR https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-admin-section-get-logined-user-detail-and-its-role/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento 2 you can do it by instantiating **`model object`** using dependency injection to inject its `factory object`. Please refer to this article, [Factory Object for model in Magento 2,](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/factory-object-magento-2.html) to understand more.

Check code below:

```
/** @var \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory  */
protected $userFactory;

/**
 * constructor.
 * @param \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory
)
{
   $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
}
```

In your **`public method`** you can get admin detail like this:

```
public function getAdminDetails()
{
    //By username get admin User's Details
    $username = 'admin';
    $user = $this->userFactory->create()->loadByUsername($username);
    $user->getStoredData();
    //get specific data like username
    //$user->getUserName();
    var_dump($user);

    //By id get admin User's Details
    $id = 1;
    $user = $this->userFactory->create()->load($id);
    $user->getStoredData();
    //get specific data like username
    //$user->getUserName();
    var_dump($user);

}
```

Comment: ! sorry is not work . i create log. and check dubug.log . return null

Comment: try to change line `var_dump($user);` to `return print_r($user);`

Comment: what did you get by the way? did you get any error message?

Comment: please it 
`$userid=28;
        $userdetail=$this->userFactory->create()->load($userid);
        $this->logger->debug(' User Email is '.$userdetail->getEmail());`

in debug.log file `main.DEBUG:  User Email is  [] []`
null value return. i also try loadByUsername($username) but nor work.

Comment: make sure to run upgrade to generate Factory class of model user

Comment: not i don't run upgrade. let me run then i will . actually var_dump or print_r() is not work because i work on place order event fire

Comment: okay try run the upgrade then let me know if it works

Comment: no dear!  i run upgrade comman and also di:compile  `$userid=28;
        $userdetail=$this->userFactory->create()->load($userid);
        $this->logger->debug(' User Email is '.$userdetail->getEmail());`
null in log file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91954/discussion-between-magefms-and-hafiz-umer).

Comment: Yes it work thanks